# Python Pandas: Compare two CSV files and delete lines from both the file by matching a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, file-manipulation

We need to delete lines from both of the files if the value of the first column is not present in the other file.

*Lets consider two CSV files*:

```
file1.csv:
yrdi_391    111    1.11    1.0    1.1    111.0
yfyrn_9132  222    2.22    2.0    2.2    222.0
kdkfke_392  999    9.99    9.0    9.9    999.0
hfeisk_3    333    3.33    3.0    3.3    333.0

file2.csv:
yrdi_391    444    4.44    4.0    4.4    444.0
yfyrn_9132  555    5.55    5.0    5.5    555.0
hfeisk_3    666    6.66    6.0    6.6    666.0
fhedn_271   888    8.88    8.0    8.8    888.0
```

Now, we need to delete entire line starting with `kdkfke_392` from the `file1.csv` as it's not present therein `file2.csv`.

On the other hand, we need to delete the entire line starting with `fhedn_271`, as it's not present in `file1.csv`.

*Expected result*:

```
file1.csv:
yrdi_391    111    1.11    1.0    1.1    111.0
yfyrn_9132  222    2.22    2.0    2.2    222.0
hfeisk_3    333    3.33    3.0    3.3    333.0

file2.csv:
yrdi_391    444    4.44    4.0    4.4    444.0
yfyrn_9132  555    5.55    5.0    5.5    555.0
hfeisk_3    666    6.66    6.0    6.6    666.0
```

As of now, the lines in `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` are not sorted. 
If required, we may do the sorting first and then apply the deletion.

Pandas CVS related manipulations are preferred as in both of the files we have headers and need to keep them.

Newbie in python scripting!

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Read about merge in pandas..

Comment: @RahulAgarwal I do not want to join these files. Need to update them while keeping them separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html).

```
print (df)

            0    1     2    3    4      5
0    yrdi_391  111  1.11  1.0  1.1  111.0
1  yfyrn_9132  222  2.22  2.0  2.2  222.0
2  kdkfke_392  999  9.99  9.0  9.9  999.0
3    hfeisk_3  333  3.33  3.0  3.3  333.0

print (df1)

            0    1     2    3    4      5
0    yrdi_391  444  4.44  4.0  4.4  444.0
1  yfyrn_9132  555  5.55  5.0  5.5  555.0
2    hfeisk_3  666  6.66  6.0  6.6  666.0
3   fhedn_271  888  8.88  8.0  8.8  888.0
```

---

```
csv_df = df[df[0].isin(df1[0])]

print (csv_df)
            0    1     2    3    4      5
0    yrdi_391  111  1.11  1.0  1.1  111.0
1  yfyrn_9132  222  2.22  2.0  2.2  222.0
3    hfeisk_3  333  3.33  3.0  3.3  333.0

csv_df1 = df1[df1[0].isin(df[0])]

print (csv_df1)
            0    1     2    3    4      5
0    yrdi_391  444  4.44  4.0  4.4  444.0
1  yfyrn_9132  555  5.55  5.0  5.5  555.0
2    hfeisk_3  666  6.66  6.0  6.6  666.0

csv_df.to_csv('temp.csv', index=False)
csv_df1.to_csv('temp1.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Giving a couple of exceptions!

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2525, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 117, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 139, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1265, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 0

_and another one_

Comment: @RandomCoder You have to use your first column name which you want to check in place of `0`  something like `df[df[your col name].isin(df1[your col name])]`